# Conditionals and Loops exercise

Tags: java

Im stuck with an exercise Im doing it says "Write a program that determines and prints the number of odd,even, and zero digits in an integer value read from the keyboard.What am I doing wrong and how can I correct my mistakes?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class OddEven {
   public static void main(String[] args){
   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

   int odd=0;
   int even=0;
   int zero=0;
   int num=0;
   int value;

   System.out.println("Enter a value: ");
   value=scan.nextInt();
   if (value%2==0)
       even=even+1;
   else
       odd=odd+1;
   System.out.println("even = "+ even);
   System.out.println("odd = "+odd);
   System.out.println("zero = "+zero);
   }
}
```

Comment: Did your code compile without errors? If it compiles, what does it, what do you expect.I see "loop" in your title, but I do not see any loop in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check for each digit at a time:

```
int odd, even, zero, value;
value = scan.nextInt();

while(value > 0) {
    int digit = value%10; //isolates only the last digit
    if(digit==0)zero++;
    else if(digit%2==0)even++;
    else odd++;
    value /= 10; //removes the last digit
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The conditional statement

```
if (value%2==0)
    even=even+1;
else
    odd=odd+1;
```

does not *count* the odd or even digits. It simply determines whether the entered value (the *whole* value) is odd or even.

As this is obviously a homework question, I will only give some hints:

1. You have to loop through all digits. In a decimal system there is an easy integer way to both get the last digit and the remaining digits as a new but smaller integer value.
2. Once you have the single (last) digit, you can check it for being odd, even, or zero.
3. The loop ends when the *remaining* value from step 1 gets 0. Some caution: There must be a special check at the beginning because the original value could have been already 0.

Look at the other answers that already provide you some code. But as a beginner you really should first try to write that code yourself.